# Windows 11 end task closes oldest task instead of the one selected

Tags: windows, taskbar

When I try to directly end task via task bar (windows 11 option), if I have multiple instances of the same task running, windows always chooses the first game window opened instead of the one Im selecting.

To be more specific, I use windhawk to separate the icons in the task bar, and if I want to close a specific window, for example of a notepad, if I select 1 out of 5 notepads windows will automatically always choose the first note pad opened to end the task, instead of the one I am selecting.

Is there any way to get windows to end the task I am selecting in the taskbar, instead of the first open window of that specific task?

EDIT: I select the taskbar icon of the windows I want to close and click end task (windows11 option), and windows automatically chooses to end the first task opened.
Sadly without windhawk it just closes all windows (of the same process) entirely.

Comment: How are you ending the tasks currently in the task bar? Please give us some more details so we can understand better HOW you are currently doing it, and this will give us a better idea what needs to be corrected. Use the EDIT button to make your question more clear.

Comment: Undo the windhawk patch - these patches are not perfect. Then you should be able to better distinguish the windows.

Comment: You might be happier with the [RetroBar](https://github.com/dremin/RetroBar).